# How to test C# method that uses SQL Connection and stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, nunit

I am currently facing a big issue where I need to test a method that uses a SQL Server connection and a stored procedure in nUnit. For some reason, when I try to mock the repository and I initialize the dependencies the method always crashed.

This is my method:

```
public int RunStoredProcedure()
{
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        string connetionString = null;

        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlParameter param;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        int i = 0;

        connetionString = _myConnectionRepo.ConnectionString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "SPCOUNTRY";

        param = new SqlParameter("@COUNTRY", "Germany");
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.DbType = DbType.String;
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }

        connection.Close();
}
```

And the unit test is:

```
[Test]
public void Should_Return_String_list()
{
        _repository.Setup(r => r.RunStoredProcedure()).Returns(new List<string>
        {
            "string1",
            "string2",
            "string3"
        });
        _cnxStringService
             .SetUp(x => x.GetConnectionString)
             .Returns("MockConnectionString");
        var result = _repository.RunStoredProcedure();

        Assert.That(result, It.IsNotNull);
}
```

When I run the project it works perfect, it returns the values correctly but the unit test says that connection string should be null, and I tried to pass it a simple string but it says the format is not correct, also I tried with a random connection string and it says there is no connection but if I pass the local connection string it works, however when I push my changes the in repo it crashes.

Can somebody help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You setup `r.RunStoredProcedure()` that returns a list of strings, but the method you posted returns an integer. Are you mocking the wrong thing? Also, you're hard coding the connection string in the method?

Comment: You don't mock the thing you're trying to test, you mock the **dependencies** of the thing you're trying to test.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. The first code block `RunStoredProcedure` doesn't have a `return` and doesn't compile. We don't know what's going on with the variables in the test method. What does _videoService type look like, the actual thing you're testing? Are you using interfaces?

Comment: Yes, I am using interfaces and repositories, basically the problem is in the unit test, because when it gets into the method after debugging, the connection string says it is empty, and it crashes.

Comment: The problem is in the unit test not in the code of the method properly.

Comment: _myConnectionRepo.ConnectionString goes to another repo and gets an environment variable and returns the connection string.

Comment: When you mock a method it does not run it so if it complains about a connection string then you are not calling the mock. In your actual code base, what Type is using `_repository`? Inject your mock into that thing and call the method on that thing that uses `repository`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, it says that the connection string should not be null, I actually debug the test and effectively it was null, but I don´t understand why.

Comment: I actually added the mock connection string but it displays it  format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting.

Comment: Side point: you need `using` on all your SQL objects to dispose them properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by my own, the solution is the following, to avoid null reference in Unit Test (nUnit) what we must do is create a two separate methods, one to retrieve a connection string from the reference project and other to split the values of that connection string.

```
private static string ReturnConnectionString(IEnumerable<JToken> jTokenValues)
    {
        var cnxString = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < jTokenValues.Count(); i++)
        {
            var str1 = jTokenValues.ElementAt(i);

            foreach (JProperty attributeProperty in str1)
            {
                if (attributeProperty.Name == "SqlConnectionString")
                {
                    var attribute = str1[attributeProperty.Name];
                    cnxString = attribute.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        return cnxString;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<JToken> ConfigureEnvironmentVariablesFromLocalSettings()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(DimAccountRepository)
            .Assembly.Location); var json =
                File.ReadAllText(Path.Join(path, "local.settings.json"));
        var parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json).Values();

        return parsed;
    }
```

thanks to this we can initialize the service and pass a connection string and avoid null references.